# update from such a repository can't be done securely on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: apt, server, updates, 22.04

Update from such a  repository can't be done securely Ubuntu Server 22.04.

[image]

---

If I use vmware then I want to download such issues arise. The version I want to download is ubuntu server 22.04 LTS.

I do all the downloads correctly, but there are still some issues

I am writing commands to update and upgrade but cannot perform errors are displayed

Command name . Sudo apt update or Sudo apt upgrade

None of this works

Comment: I want you to help

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  No such product, do you mean Ubuntu Core 22 server?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server which your picture seems to show.  Please don't provide pictures of text, paste the text itself into your question as it's easier to read, and we can copy/paste details so we can look up details. Please be accurate with details as your paste doesn't look like a Ubuntu Core 22 Server system (22 & 22.04 are different products)

Comment: 0


If I use vmware then I want to download such issues arise. The version I want to download is ubuntu server 22.04 LTS.

I do all the downloads correctly, but there are still some issues

I am writing commands to update and upgrade but cannot perform errors are displayed

Command name . Sudo apt update or Sudo apt upgrade

None of this works